# Web API Requests Authentication

Tags: python, python-requests, request-headers

I am trying a get request using the following API info:

https://github.com/iblockin/pool_web_api_doc/blob/master/api_en.md

Can someone help me with what the headers should look like, or point out where I am messing up? I keep getting an unauthenticated response.

```py
url = "https://api-prod.poolin.com/api/public/v1/subaccount"

r = requests.get(url, headers =  {'authorization': 'accessToken tokenhere'})
```

Sorry in advance if this has been inevitably answered in 1000 other locations.

**Severe noob here, trying to learn**

Comment: Are you adding your token besides accessToken or are you executing the code your provided literally?

Comment: @SamirAhmane I am replacing with my token, still receiving "Unauthenticated"

Comment: I think you should change accessToken to Bearer according to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
url = "https://api-prod.poolin.com/api/public/v1/subaccount"

r = requests.get(url, headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer tokenhere'})
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/iblockin/pool_web_api_doc/blob/master/api_en.md#note-authentication-requires-passing-the-accesstoken-in-the-request-header-the-parameter-name-is-authorization-the-value-is-bearer-token-and-token-is-replaced-with-the-token-value-to-be-transmitted) accessToken should be passed in the `header`as

```
{'authorization':'Bearer TOKEN'} # TOKEN is replaced with the token value to be transmitted
```

So correct your code accordingly.